# Weird glitch of UISwitch related to the UIScrollView on iOS with C#

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, uiswitch

I have ViewContoller, and it is view hierarchy is the following (Cirrious.FluentLayout Library, but It should be understandable):

```
        _scrollView = new UIScrollView()
        {
            ShowsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        };
        View.Add(_scrollView);

        _contentView = new UIView();
        _scrollView.Add(_contentView);


        View.AddConstraints(
            _scrollView.Below(VueNavBar),
            _scrollView.AtLeftOf(View),
            _scrollView.AtRightOf(View),
            _scrollView.AtBottomOf(View)
        );

        _scrollView.AddConstraints(_contentView.SameFrameAs(_scrollView));
```

Then I add UISwitch in the following way:

```
var switch = new UISwitch();
_contentView.Add(switch);
```

After setting up constraints (I have tried many sets of constraints, many of them are definitely not ambiguous) iOS renders me the following:

[image: Bad Switch]

It is really weird, but after toggling it changes to:

[image: Bad switch after toggling]

Maybe someone have any ideas why it happens?

P.S.: I have managed to broke switches on other pages by adding scroll view in the same way, however they have been broken in a differently (Other type of glitch).

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code below and the switch displayed normally.

And there is no need for you to define the width and height of a `UISwitch`.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            _scrollView = new UIScrollView()
            {
                ShowsVerticalScrollIndicator = false,
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue
            };
            View.Add(_scrollView);

            this.View.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();

            View.AddConstraints(
                _scrollView.AtTopOf(View,20),
                _scrollView.AtLeftOf(View,20),
                _scrollView.AtRightOf(View, 20),
                _scrollView.AtBottomOf(View, 20)
            );

            _contentView = new UIView();
            _contentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Orange;
            _scrollView.Add(_contentView);

            _scrollView.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();

            _scrollView.AddConstraints(
             _contentView.WithSameTop(_scrollView),
             _contentView.WithSameLeft(_scrollView),
             _contentView.WithSameWidth(_scrollView),
              _contentView.WithSameHeight(_scrollView)
            );

            var switch1 = new UISwitch();
            _contentView.Add(switch1);
            _contentView.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();
            _contentView.AddConstraints(
                switch1.AtTopOf(_contentView, 80),
                switch1.AtLeftOf(_contentView, 20)
            );

        }
```

[image: switch]

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I don't set the width and height of UISwitch.